# Разбить на несколько слов php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня есть данные, которые хранятся как строка. Разделены они символом ***","*** 
Например,

```
name - 'Новострой'
add_options - 'Сдан, Не сдан'.
```

Каким образом можно разделить значения в add_options таким образом, чтобы получилось 2 значения:

```
1 Здан 
2 Не сдан
```

И чтобы потом была возможность использовать их в select ??

Comment: `explode(',',$add_options);`

Answer (score 2):

Используй функцию [explode:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$add_options = "Сдан, Не сдан";
$add_options = explode(',', $add_options);
foreach($add_options as $option){
    echo $option.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: надо не забыть `trim`, ибо пробельчик после запятой `explode` сам не уберет

Answer (score 0):

Лучше через `preg_split`, чтобы сразу убрать пробелы

```
$add_options = "Сдан, Не сдан";
$add_options = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $add_options);
```

**UPD** В комментариях верно поправили. Спасибо @Firepro

Comment: поверьте лучше `explode`,`trim` чем `preg_split`

Comment: с удовольствием выслушаю, чем лучше

Comment: проалгоритмы прочитайте, `explode` один раз обходит строку, а `preg_split` обходит в зависимости от маски... Так что explode лучше и быстрей.

Comment: Отличная экономия на спичках

Comment: А потом foreach-ем пройтись с trim с переприсваиванием, ок

Comment: Ах да, пройтись через for, ведь он быстрей foreach

Comment: explode будет быстрее на большой выборке, здесь же разницы нет. @OotzlyGootzly ваш пример будет возвращать 3 строки, вместо нужных двух.

Comment: `Ах да, пройтись через for, ведь он быстрей foreach`  можно даже `$array = array_map('trim', $array);` ;D